# ReactJS Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop, use-effect, use-state

I'm so stuck.
Here is the code;

```
 const Destination = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const destinationUrl = props.match.params.dest_url;
  const [destination, setDestination] = React.useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!destination) {
      getDestinationByUrl(destinationUrl).then((destination) => {
        console.log("destination", destination); //result is attached below
        setDestination(destination);
      });
    }
  }, [destination]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={3} className={classes.mainGrid}>
        {destination && (
          <>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Typography variant="h5" className="title">
                {destination.title}
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <DestinationRightBar destination={destination} />
          </>
        )}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

it gives this error on "setDestination(destination);"
[image]

it also says error occured on DestinationRightBar

[image]

If I remove destination right bar it works!
What is the right way to make it work!

getDestinationByUrl is a fetch

```
export function getDestinationByUrl(url) {
  return fetch(baseUrl + url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
    },
  })
    .then((response) =>
      response.ok ? response.json().then(handleResponse) : handleNotOk(response)
    )
    .catch(handleError);
}
```

Value of destination object is
[image]

DestinationRightBar is just another component which uses destination object as input.

```
export default function DestinationRightBar(props) {
  const { destination } = props;
```

Comment: can you add `getDestinationByUrl` code? cause its really weird

Comment: I added, it is just a fetch

Comment: What is the value of `destination` when you have set it using `setDestination`.

Comment: The value of destination is a json object.

Comment: I have edited the added the object

Comment: the thing here is why it works as expected when I remove the "DestinationRightBar"  part?

Comment: Can you also add that DestinationRightBar code? Also where is the const getDest =  part?

Comment: I've updated question, since the code is big I'm not pasting all of it. DestinationRightBar is just a component which uses destination as an input.

Comment: Since `destination` is an object, every time you set it react will see that as a new reference.
You should use a primitive as a dependency. 
Use, `destination.id` as a dep or do a check of a property inside destination.
Currently you are just checking `if(!destination)`

Comment: I did, "if (!destination.id) { " and ", [destination.id]" but it didn't work, same error!

Comment: It is impossible, if you have `destination.id` then your `if(!destination.id)` would turn into `if(false)`.
Then `setDestination` would never be called for the second time.
Can you provide a codesandbox replicating your issue?.

Also do initialize your destination as {}.
You can do so by `const [destination, setDestination] = React.useState({});`

Comment: can you add full `DestinationRightBar` code or at least the part you `destination` in? probably you refer something to it outside `useEffect` or something, and because `destination` set at parent `useEffect` first render, Bar gonna into infinite loop

Comment: In DestinationRightBar component this piece of code was causing the problem but why?   if (destination.tags) {
    setTags(destination.tags.split(","));
  }

Answer (score 1):

Your `useEffect` code really does not make any sense. With that code, you say when the destination changes, run the effect, but in your effect you have `if (!destination)` which means if destination is falsy call the api, why???
Even worse, you try to change the value of destination inside the effect which will cause infinite loop.

Please spend a few hours to learn how `useEffect` works.

[Official Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for useEffect.

[Dan Abramov's complete guide about useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/).

I believe you should use `destinationUrl` as dependency in the useEffect.
Which means call the api when the destinationUrl changes, which make sense.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (destinationUrl) {
      getDestinationByUrl(destinationUrl).then((destination) => {
        setDestination(destination);
      });
    }
  }, [destinationUrl]);
```

Comment: since destinationUrl has value, if I put it in "if " statement request not sent.

Comment: @KubilayBayraktar I updated, it must be if (destinationUrl) but not if (!destinationUrl)

Comment: @KubilayBayraktar but did this solve the `React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop` problem?

Comment: I solved the problem by removing this piece of code which is in DestinationRightBar component: **setTags(destination.tags.split(","));**

Comment: @KubilayBayraktar you mentioned 2 problems, one of them was infinite loop problem. Without using my solution, did removing that component also solve the infinite loop?

Comment: yes, when I removed that piece of code, everything just worked well.